# Entity Framework 5: Concatenate two fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to concatenate two fields and list all items of a database class. Using `Entity framework` and `ASP.Net MVC`'s list method, why can't I do something like this?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName + " " + item.Lname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Accounts", "Accounts", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CustomerID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Customer' does not contain a definition for 'Lname' and no extension method 'Lname' accepting a first argument of type 'Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
```

Alternatively, add a property to your model:

```
public string FullName { get { return FName + " " + LName; } }
```

and then do:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
```

Additional note:

Upon further inspection of your error, I suspect that you have mistyped `Lname` - perhaps you meant `LName`? Regardless, using concatenation in that way will not work and will result in this error, instead:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.